# How to have multiple PagedListRenderOptions in PagedList.Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am working with c# and I am making an Ajax call using PagedList.Mvc. The code in my cshtml view is the following:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.PagedList, page => Url.Action("SearchTable", "JobOffer", 
    new {
        randomParameters = "BANANAS"
        page = page
    }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(
        new AjaxOptions() { 
            HttpMethod = "GET", 
            UpdateTargetId = "tableAndPaginationDiv" 
        }
    )
)
```

However, I also want to have `PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing of this answer, having more than one `PagedListRenderOptions`is not possible. After checking the documentation, I realized that if you want something like that, the only way is to create a custom option yourself, greatly increasing the complexity of the solution:

- http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/PagedList.Mvc/PagedList.Mvc/PagedListRenderOptions
- https://gist.github.com/troygoode/1053136

Answer (score 3):

Actually, how about trying this:

```
    @{
    var pLRO = PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(
          new AjaxOptions() { 
             HttpMethod = "GET", 
             UpdateTargetId = "tableAndPaginationDiv" 
          }
       );
    //and now here set all the properties you want
    pLRO.DisplayLinkToFirstPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always;
    pLRO.DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always;
    //you can even style the format
    pLRO.LinkToFirstPageFormat = "First";
    pLRO.LinkToLastPageFormat = "Last";
    }
    //the rest of your view
    //...
    //and when you insert the pager just pass the pLRO variable
   @Html.PagedListPager(Model.PagedList, page => Url.Action("SearchTable",     "JobOffer", 
     new {
      randomParameters = "BANANAS"
      page = page
     }), pLRO 
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation it looks as if one can now have multiple options.

```
    @Html.PagedListPager(
            (IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts,
            page => Url.Action( "Index", 
                                 new { page = page }), 
                                 new PagedListRenderOptions { LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<< Primera", LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "< Anterior", LinkToNextPageFormat = "Siguiente >", LinkToLastPageFormat = "Ultima >>" }
            );
```

[Documentation on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/troygoode/1053136)